# My friend function is not executing

Tags: c++, friend-function

I have declared a friend function in my header file, and defined it in my .cpp file, but when I compile I am told that the variables 'have not been declared in this scope'.  It's my understanding that when a function is labeled a friend of a class, that function is able to directly access all members of that class, so why would I get this error?

My .h file:

```
#ifndef EMPLOYEE_H
#define EMPLOYEE_H

#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Employee
{
  friend void SetSalary(Employee& emp2);

 private:

  string name;
  const long officeNo;
  const long empID;
  int deptNo;
  char empPosition;
  int yearOfExp;
  float salary;
  static int totalEmps;
  static int nextEmpID;
  static int nextOfficeNo;

 public:
  Employee();
  ~Employee();
  Employee(string theName, int theDeptNo, char theEmpPosition, int theYearofExp);
  void Print() const;
  void GetInfo();
};

#endif
```

function in my.cpp file

```
void SetSalary(Employee& emp2)
{

  while (empPosition == 'E')
    {
      if (yearOfExp < 2)
        salary = 50000;
      else
        salary = 55000;
    }
}
```

Note:  In my Main.cpp, I am creating an object 'emp2'.  This is being passed as a parameter into the function.

Answer (score 4):

`empPosition`, `yearOfExp` and `salary` are members of the `Employee` class, so you need

```
while (emp2.empPosition == 'E') ....
//     ^^^^
```

and similarly for the expressions involving `yearOfExp` and `salary`. `friend` functions are non-member functions, so they can only access data members of the class they are friends of via an instance of that class (`emp2` in this case).

Comment: Wow...after going back and forth between the header and .cpp, I didn't once thing about that. I should have noticed that last night.